# Not getting the required response from the router with OCNOS. In Python

Tags: python, shell, ssh, router, paramiko

As mention in the response, the commands are successfully executed on the router. But the response is incomplete or incorrect. May I am not reading the response correctly. How can I read the correct response?

```
import paramiko
import logging

# Enable debug-level logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

hostname = '10.1.1.86'
port = 22
username = '***'
password = '***'

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

try:

    # Enable logging to a file
    paramiko.util.log_to_file("paramiko.log")
    ssh_client.connect(hostname=hostname, port=port, username=username, password=password)
    
    shell = ssh_client.invoke_shell()
    #shell.send("show version\n")
    #output = shell.recv(65535).decode()
    
    commands = [
        'enable',
        'show version',
        'show ip route',
    ]

    for command in commands:
        shell.send(command)
        output = shell.recv(65535).decode()
        print("Command Output:")
        print(output)
        print("--- COMMAND EXECUTION FINISHED ---")

except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
    print("Authentication failed, please verify your credentials.")
except paramiko.SSHException as e:
    print("SSH connection failed:", str(e))
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", str(e))
finally:
    ssh_client.close()
```

Here is the response from the router...

```
Command Output:
Linux CSGW-N1 4.19.91-g1790faa27 #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 15:51:25 UTC 2022 x86_64
Last login: Tue Oct  8 11:15:28 2019 from 10.1.1.88

--- COMMAND EXECUTION FINISHED ---
Command Output:
enable
--- COMMAND EXECUTION FINISHED ---
Command Output:
show version
--- COMMAND EXECUTION FINISHED ---
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:EOF in transport thread
```

Most of the help is available for CISCO devices but this using a OCNOS.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after the commands.

I.e. depending on the remote system, `\n` or `\r` (or even `\r\n`).

---

Also note that your code hardly reads outputs of the individual commands. It's not possible with `invoke_shell`. Your code incorrectly claims that *"command execution finished"* after `recv` returns.
[How to detect if command executed using Paramiko invoke_shell has finished](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53707630/850848)
[Execute several commands on Cisco switch via Paramiko - improve performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50015532/850848)

---

*In general, you should not use `invoke_shell`, but I understand that you device might not support proper `exec_command`.*
*[Executing command using Paramiko exec_command on device is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30603219/850848)*

Comment: Thank you answers. I figure it out. I have the both issues, not reading a complete response and "\n". I am sharing a updated code below.

Comment: but I don't understand why the code incorrectly claims that the "command execution finished".

Comment: @WaleedAkbar My answer includes two links that explain why. Did you follow them?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code.

```py
for command in commands:
    # Send command and wait for the shell prompt before sending the next command
    shell.send(command + '\n')

    while not shell.recv_ready():
        time.sleep(3)

    response = shell.recv(65535).decode()
    responses.append(response)
```